# how to get result which is returned with C callback in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, design-patterns, callback

I am rather new to handle C callbacks in C++. I made a sqlite wrapper c++ class, which just calls sqlite3_exec().

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  SqliteAccessor* sqlite = static_cast<SqliteAccessor*> NotUsed; 
  if(argc > 0) { 
    sqlite->set_table_exists(true); 
  }
  return 0;
}

class SqliteAccessor{    
public:
bool has_table(const string dbName, const string tblName)
{
  string sql;
  sql = "SELECT " + quote_string(tblName) + "FROM " + quote_string(dbName)
           + "WHERE type = 'table' AND name = " + quote_string(tblName) + ";";
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql.c_str(), callback, (void*) this, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    printf("SQL error: %s", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }
  // anyway to return the result directly?
  // return hasTable;
}

// can I avoid the following methods and the member variable? 
void set_table_exists(bool isExist) { m_table_exist = isExist; }
bool get_table_exists() { return m_table_exist; }
private: 
  static bool m_table_exist; 
};

int caller(){
   SqliteAccessor sqlite;
   // to check if table exist
   if (sqlite->has_table()){
      // will above work or 
      // I should do with an extra call to query the changed state?        
   }
}
```

Now, I am quite confused how the caller can get the result from sqlite wrapper. I think, the caller cannot have the result by simply calling `has_table()`, because the result is returned from the callback, by `set_table_exists()`. So shall the caller get the result by making another call, e.g. call `sqlite->get_table_exists()` ?

Then this implies for every callback, I need to make a member variable (also has to be `static`) in class SqliteAccessor, and a pair of `set/get_state()`, which will be very cumbersome.

How to design the class to make it nice to use by caller?
Unfortunately, our code base does not support c++11.

Comment: that is the result set by the callback. I want to avoid it.

Comment: `hasTable`  does not get changed once it is initialized to `false`, do `has_table()` always returns `false`.  If `sqlite->get_table_exists()` does exist, that is what `has_table()` should return. Then the user of `SqliteAccessor` doesn't need to call anything but `has_table()`.

Comment: my bad, I revised it. thanks!

Comment: Your question is missing code though. You call a member function `set_table_exists(true)`, but you don't show its implementation. What does it do? If it sets a member bool variable to true, then yes, `has_table()` can just return it's value.

Comment: can I? is it already set by the callback? i have updated my code with these two functions. thanks!

Comment: You can avoid those methods. Look at my answer :) You do require for `SqliteAccessor` to have state though. I don't think there is a way around that.

Comment: Why aren't you using the cursor-based interface?

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide an example how this can be done with cursor? I saw some example with cursor based on andrioid, I thought that is android specific. am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is to make the callback a private static member function and basically do what you did. Like this:

```
class SqliteAccessor
{
public:
    bool has_table(const std::string dbName, const std::string tblName);

private:
    static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);

    bool m_hasTable;
};

int SqliteAccessor::callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
     SqliteAccessor* sqlite = static_cast<SqliteAccessor*>(NotUsed);
     if(argc > 0) sqlite->m_hasTable = true;
     return 0;
}


bool SqliteAccessor::has_table(const std::string dbName, const std::string tblName)
{
    m_hasTable = false;
    string sql = "SELECT " + quote_string(tblName) + "FROM " + quote_string(dbName)
           + "WHERE type = 'table' AND name = " + quote_string(tblName) + ";";
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql.c_str(), callback, (void*) this, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        printf("SQL error: %s", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }

    return m_hasTable;
}

int caller()
{
   SqliteAccessor sqlite;
   // to check if table exist
   if (sqlite.has_table())
   {
      // do stuff :)
   }
}
```

If sqlite3_exec() does not work with static functions, you can try with a global function like this:

```
class SqliteAccessor
{
public:
    bool has_table(const std::string dbName, const std::string tblName);

private:    
    bool m_hasTable;

    friend int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);
};

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
     SqliteAccessor* sqlite = static_cast<SqliteAccessor*>(NotUsed);
     if(argc > 0) sqlite->m_hasTable = true;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: good. is there a better way to do it? because if I have 100 callbacks, then I would have 100 private callbacks, 100 member variables. That is quite annoying.

Comment: @pepero You only have 1 callback, not 100. Member variables only cost space if you have an object alive. So if you have to make 100 callbaks in sequence, you can use the same `SqliteAccessor` and keep calling `has_table()` with different parameters. This will only cost you 1 bool variable (so 4 bytes on 32 bit machine).

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your "only 1 callback." If I have two different methods with two different sql queries, e.g. has_table and remove_entry, I guess I have to make two callbacks? am I right? also, I do not really like this way since you have to make all these member variables static

Comment: @pepero Ture for every different callback, you need a new callback function. Even in C++11 you would then need 100 lambda functions :) There is no static member variables. Just normal variables that will hold information that a callback will want to return. You can probably use the same variables for different callbacks. For every callback that  returns a bool you can use a bool member variable since you won't use more than one callback at once. I don't think there is a better way for callbacks in general, I am sorry.

Comment: the callback function is static, so the member variable has to be static, isn't it?

Comment: @pepero No it doesn't, because you give your callback a pointer to a `SqliteAccessor` object that is not static (global). If you look at your `caller()` function, it creates `SqliteAccessor sqlite` on stack, so the member variable `sqlite.m_hasTable` is also on the stack, therefore not static.

Comment: i mean the m_hasTable has to be static, since the callback is static, in c++ you cannot do non-static variables in static function. Is it?

Comment: @pepero No, because you access it through a pointer to `SqliteAccessor`, which you get into the static function through its parameters. It does not have to be static. Did you compile and try it?

Comment: yes, it does not compile. error: cannot declare member function 'static int SqliteAccessor::callback(void*, int, char**, char**)' to have static linkage

Comment: @pepero I fixed the compile errors I could (I don't have the sqlite library). As to the static member variable, this code compiles fine.

Comment: yes, it compiles with your fix. amazing. I am quite surprised. so if 'm_hasTable' accessed directly, this will not be allowed (static function cannot change non-static member variables), however, if accessed via the parameter 'sqlite', it is allowed. Is this a known trick?

Comment: @pepero Think of it this way. Member functions are functions that are called on an object and can manipulate it's member variables. Static member functions are functions that are like normal functions and are not called on a object, therefore they cannot manipulate member variables, there is no object with member variables to manipulate! However if you give the static function a pointer to a object, it can manipulate it's member variables (even the private ones, since the static function is part of the class).And that is the main reason they exist. Global functions that can see private members

Comment: @pepero here are the basics of static member functions: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/ It will answer your futher questions about them :)

Comment: I did understand the relation between static member function and static member variable in the way your described in beginning. that is why I get surprised. is this violated by "passing parameter"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79432/discussion-between-rozina-and-pepero).

Comment: this does not really work, the "m_hasTable" is still false, even though the callback has set it true. really weird. i got to withdraw the acceptance.

Comment: @pepero So if you put a breakpoint in the callback function and a breakpoint at the return `m_hasTable` in `has_table()` the `m_hasTable` changes on its own? I can't imagine how that would happen.

Comment: I add some printf to trace, I could see that the callback is called and set true, then after the callback, the m_hasTable is still false, i tried with this->m_hasTable, false as well, unbelievable, but definitely something wrong here.

Comment: @pepero I edited the answer. You can try this approach. If that still doesn't work, then the bug is elsewhere in your code. Keep in mind, I don't know how sqlite3 works, I have never used it :) So I trust you are using it correctly.

Comment: rozina, my previous comment was wrong. I used tracing in a wrong place. but still, i find out the private member function callback is not called by the sqlite3 at all.

Comment: @pepero That could be due an error in the sqlite3_exec() function. It returns error codes, check them and try to figure out what is going on. Like I said, that is beyond my help. So good luck with debuging!

Comment: rozina, it is indeed due to the sqlite3_exec, if a select query to check if table exists before the table is actually created, the callback will not be called and remain silent. the sqlite callback is somehow triggered with certain conditions. Your way actually works. it is quite had to find this out. I will accept your answer. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are on C++11 consider using a lambda instead of a callback.

```
class SqliteAccessor{    
public:
bool has_table(const string dbName, const string tblName)
{
  bool hasTable = false;
  string sql;
  sql = "SELECT " + quote_string(tblName) + "FROM " + quote_string(dbName)
           + "WHERE type = 'table' AND name = " + quote_string(tblName) + ";";
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql.c_str(), [&](void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  SqliteAccessor* sqlite = static_cast<SqliteAccessor*> NotUsed; 
  if(argc > 0) { 
    hasTable = true; 
  }
 }
 , (void*) this, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    printf("SQL error: %s", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }
  return hasTable;
}
};
```

If you don't have access to C++11, you can always manually write your functor. You lose a bit of conciseness and locality though. The nice part is that the functor can save the state you need.

```
struct callback{
  bool operator(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
  {
  SqliteAccessor* sqlite = static_cast<SqliteAccessor*> NotUsed; 
  if(argc > 0) { 
    hasTable = true; 
  }
  return false;
  }
  bool hasTable;
};


class SqliteAccessor{    
public:
bool has_table(const string dbName, const string tblName)
{
  bool hasTable = false;
  string sql;
  sql = "SELECT " + quote_string(tblName) + "FROM " + quote_string(dbName)
           + "WHERE type = 'table' AND name = " + quote_string(tblName) + ";";
  char *zErrMsg = 0;

  callback c;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql.c_str(), c, (void*) this, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    printf("SQL error: %s", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }
  return c.hasTable;
}
};
```

Comment: nice! you could omit the `SqliteAccessor* sqlite = static_cast<SqliteAccessor*> NotUsed; `

Comment: unfortunately, c++11 is not available. :-(

Comment: oh that's unfortunate, but you could write your own functor to do so! 
Not quite as nice, but it coudl work as well, I'll upgrade the answe

Comment: yeah, I am really keen to know, how to make callback nice in C++.

Comment: The C++03 version only works if sqlite3_exec() is a template, which I doubt since the OP said it uses a C callback function.

Comment: yes you're right, I didn't think about that. no luck for the OP

Comment: @rozina, what do you mean? I am using the latest sqlite3 from the repo. Can sqlite3_exec() be a template? sorry I am rather new to sqlite, so maybe there is better api I could use.